# Feasibility to Bypass Address randomization and Stack Smash Protection - buffer overflow attack

Tags: c, security, unix, assembly, buffer

I just went through logic behind buffer overflow attacks and associated protection mechanisms available in kernel versions above 2.6 in UNIX to avoid buffer overflow attacks (Address Randomization and Stack Smash Protection).

In each time we go ahead disabling Address Randomization (Assigning '0' to kernel address randomization) and Stack Smash Protection (including -fno-stack-protector while compiling) to analyze buffer overflow attacks.

Just curious to get to know, Is there any bypass protection mechanism available without having to do above mentioned two activities just by disabling while it's still enforced. Would be good to hear if so any such mechanism there, can you please help on it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know of to avoid buffer overflow is to make use of 100% fully exhaustive unit tests that check any function that deals with a buffer of any size and type. This is not always realistic, of course.

> "exhaustive" means that all possible cases are taken in account, no matter whether your application would ever generate all those specific cases at time you first write your code.

Although there are tools out there that can help you in that arena. Some are quite well automated and will generate unit tests automatically. I never tried one of those so I cannot warrant any one of them, but if you are in a time crunch, that could help.

Another way, which somewhat works is to run a static analyzer against your code. Code Coverity is the one I have used in the past, but there are many others too. In most cases, static analysis will only catch problems where you declare static buffers on your stack as in:

```
 char buf[256];
 ...
 char a = buf[256];  // <- bug here, although not too bad
 buf[256] = a;       // <- bug here, could be bad, you're writing to the stack!
```

Now... under Unix you have two problems with buffer overflows. It will make your system crash in most cases. However, if the hacker has access to your code, they may be able to call a specific system function (a kernel function, to be clear). In that case, what is potentially problematic is if your process runs with an elevated user (i.e. worst case scenario: root). At that point the hacker may have obtained some permissions to do more stuff without your authorization. To eliminate this risk you have two main solutions:

1. Use a chroot environment; this can be difficult to setup if you are new to Linux, but that works on virtual all Unices
2. Use a virtualbox environment (or some other virtual system like qemu); getting such an environment setup is generally pretty easy, although if you want to automatically generate new environments... there is an API and it can be tedious.

There is one last way, but that can be slow. The CPU has an MMU. You can use the MMU to protect/unprotect the memory and ensure that each read and write happens to a buffer that was allocated (in case of the stack, the frame buffer is used to make sure you are within the correct window.) As you can imagine, for each write (and possibly many reads) you get an interrupt and the handler is not small. It's a good tool/idea to debug a software that has many buffer overflows, but in general it is not useable in production.

Unfortunately, none of these options are part of the g++ suite by default.